# Is it possible to reference a Proxy from its own handler object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I have a need to reference the current `Proxy` instance from inside its own handler. I haven't seen this mentioned in any of the documentation I've read and I'm just curious if there's any natural way to do this.

The thing is, inside the handler object, `this` naturally refers to the handler, not the `Proxy` it is the handler *of*.

For example:

```
var ProxyHandler = {
    get: function(object, property) {
        var thisProxy = ??? // how to reference myProxy from here?
    }
};

var someObj = {foo: "bar"};
var myProxy = new Proxy(someObj, ProxyHandler);

console.log(myProxy.foo);
```

Comment: No. You need to save a reference to the proxy.

Comment: (You can reference `myProxy` of course, it's in scope). I do wonder though [what you need this for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: @Bergi Explaining that would greatly complicate the question and isn't really relevant, but in short, I want to create a recursive chain of proxies for all properties accessed on an object so that I can intercept changes to any sub-property of an object, no matter how deeply nested. I need to be able to reference the parent proxy so it can properly chain together.

Comment: @devios1 A reference to the parent `target` object should be enough for that, no?

Comment: @Bergi Yes I suppose that would also work…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of a Proxy `get` handler is

```
function(target, property, receiver) {
```

so since you do `myProxy.foo`, the `receiver` argument will be `myProxy` following the standard logic for property access context.

Comment: So it is! I don't know how I missed that! I guess the examples I looked at didn't bother to include the third argument, but now that I look at the documentation you are completely right!

Comment: The receiver also could be anything that inherits the property, it might not always be the proxy itself.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of handler is as follows

```
let handler = {
    get(target, propKey, receiver) {
        return (...args) => console.log(args);
    }
};
let proxy = new Proxy({}, handler);
```

the receiver is of type Proxy and in our case it is the object **myProxy**